# Match two names from a list in Excel, no repeats

Tags: excel, match, excel-match

I am creating a spreadsheet with a list of 90 names, these names need to match up for one to one meetings and this will be repeating many times. I need to randomize these pairings and not have any repeated matches.

Answer (score 0):

There are only roughly 4000 combinations of numbers 1-90 giving you a rough total of 44 different rounds of meetings without duplicating any meetings.
I used the below website to generate the possible numbers and pasted them into an excel spreadsheet.
https://numbergenerator.org/randomnumbergenerator/combinations-generator#!numbers=2&lines=5000&low=1&high=90&unique=false&order_matters=false&csv=&oddeven=&oddqty=0&sorted=false&sets=
You are not starting from the first row but from the second row in this example
After this you will have column A with numbers 1-90 going down rows.
Column B will have names.
Column C will have =MOD(ROWS($D$2:D2)-1,90)+1 formula to make numbers 1-90 appear and once you get to 90 they will start back at 1
Column D will have formula =VLOOKUP( LEFT(C3,SEARCH(" ",C3,1))+0, $A$3:$B$92, 2, FALSE) to extract first number that you got from the website.
Column E will have formula =VLOOKUP( MID(C3,SEARCH(" ",C3,1),LEN(C3))+0, $A$3:$B$92, 2, FALSE) to extract second number that you got from the website.
A picture has been attached for clarification.[image]